# Django 1.7: some_name() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Tags: python, django, django-urls

this is my view.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
import datetime
def current_datetime(request):
     now = datetime.datetime.now()
     html = "<html><body>It is now %s.</body></html>" % now
     return HttpResponse(html)
def hours_ahead(request, offset):
     offset = int(offset)
     dt = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(hours=offset)
     html = "<html><body>In %s hour(s), it will be %s.</body></html>" % (offset, dt)
     return HttpResponse(html)
```

this is my urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url, include
from mysite.view import current_datetime, hours_ahead
urlpatterns = patterns('',
# Examples:
# url(r'^$', 'mysite.views.home', name='home'),
# url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

# url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
(r'^time/$', current_datetime),
#(r'^time/plus/\d{1,2}/$', hours_ahead),
url(r'$', 'mysite.view.hours_ahead', name='hours_ahead'),
)
```

when i try to go to this localhost:8000/time/plus/24/ 
I have the error **hours_ahead() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)**

Answer (score 3):

You need to [capture](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#captured-parameters) the offset from the url:

```
url(r'^time/plus/(\d+)/$', 'mysite.view.hours_ahead', name='hours_ahead'),
```

where `(\d+)` is a capturing group that would capture one or more digits. In case of `localhost:8000/time/plus/24/` it would capture `24`.

Answer (score 0):

offset is missing here:

```
url(r'$', 'mysite.view.hours_ahead', name='hours_ahead'),
```