# about Django ,"url() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)"

Tags: python, django

this is my views.py

```
    def hours_ahead(request, offset):
        try:
            offset = int(offset)
        except ValueError:
            raise Http404()
        dt = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(hours=offset)
        assert False
        html = "<html><body>In %s hour(s), it will be %s.</body></html>" % (offset, dt)
        return HttpResponse(html)
```

and this is my urls.py

```
    from mysite.views import current_datetime,hours_ahead   
    urlpatterns = patterns('',
     # Examples:
        url(r'^$', 'mysite.views.home', name='home'),
        url(r'^blog/', include("blog.urls", namespace="blog")),
        url(r'^current_datetime/$', current_datetime),     
        url(url(r'^time/plus/\d+/$', 'mysite.view.hours_ahead', name='hours_ahead')),
        url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

the errow is

```
    TypeError at /
    url() takes at least 2 arguments (2 given)
```

and I found same problem in this page              [Django 1.7: some_name() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26113260/django-1-7-some-name-takes-exactly-2-arguments-1-given)
If I change my code like that suggestion
the error message turn to this :

```
    ViewDoesNotExist at /
    Could not import mysite.views.home. View does not exist in module mysite.views.
```

and in my opinion , I do not believe the reason of bug is lack  "mysite.view.hours_ahead"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is in this line:

```
url(url(r'^time/plus/\d+/$', 'mysite.view.hours_ahead', name='hours_ahead')),
```

It should be:

```
url(r'^time/plus/(\d+)/$', 'mysite.views.hours_ahead', name='hours_ahead'),
```

Comment: thanks for your help :) ,but that's my type mistake,change that can not do anything .But I just found the solution~ thank you again:)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution
this  line

```
     url(r'^time/plus/\d+/$', 'mysite.view.hours_ahead', name='hours_ahead'),
```

should be

```
    url(r'^time/plus/(?P<offset>\d{1,2})/$', hours_ahead)
```

It seems like some problem about parameter passing and Regex.